# Should I be using Blender game engine as my first engine?

Tags: blender

I am new to game development. I was learning how to create 3d models in Blender to use in an Android game, but I was reading that you can use Blender game engine for creating android games.

Is it a good idea to use it since I couldn't find any reviews about it. Is it actually being used by developers to create Android games?

Comment: Welcome to the site Omar. Please see the [FAQ] about what type of questions to ask here. This one isn't constructive since there's no *correct* answer someone can give (just opinions, not supported by facts).

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to test your idea in Blender app engine as a new 3D modeller. The game engine requires less programming knowledge, free, and you don't need reviews because it already has a great community. It is not as widely used by developers as other commercial game engines but it is still a good start.

Comment: Agreed. Blender is really nice for a quick setup. You also can do almost everything inside blender. As opposed to using a few different programs and then putting them all together in another program. I'd suggest going through some tutorials.